# Why does jQuery not work with a piece of html that jQuery added to the page via Ajax?

Tags: html, dom, jquery

The code below simply submits a form via Ajax and appends the result from the addNewUser.php script into a small popup window.

```
//activate the signup submit button
$('#button_signup_submit').click(function() {

    document.getElementById("popup_signup").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("popup_signup_step_two").style.display = "block";
    //submit the form info via ajax to addNewUser.php
    $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "ajax/addNewUser.php",
         data: { 
            username: document.forms["form_signup"]["username"].value,
            password: document.forms["form_signup"]["password"].value
         },
         datatype: "html",
         success: function(data){

                    var jqObj = jQuery(data);
                    $('#popup_signup_step_two').append(jqObj)
                }
    });

});
```

I can get the above script to append the ajaxed html into the original webpage no problem... but when I go to use my second piece of code:

```
//activate the second signup page's return button
$('#return_to_signup_form_from_ajax_popup').click(function() {
    alert("HEY");
    //erase innerHtml of popup_signup_step_two
    document.getElementById("popup_signup_step_two").innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById("popup_signup_step_two").style.display = "none";

    //show the original signup form again, should contain user's original values
    document.getElementById("popup_background").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("popup_login").style.display = "block";

});
```

...which is a jQuery snippet that works with the newly added html... nothing happens. That second piece of code applies when the user forgets to enter a username or password and they are given this message via ajax:

```
<p>Go <span id="return_to_signup_form_from_ajax_popup">back</span> and enter a username and password.</p>
```

I assume this all has something to do with the DOM? But ultimately I have no idea. If anybody could even point me in the direction of what to look for I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as long as you are sure the response is giving the proper html back - you should be doin alright. I would recommend changing your click handler to be a delegated handler instead - then you dont have to worry about if it was initialized before or after the ajax'd html was added to the live dom.

EDIT: updated  to use latest jquery `on` method. (http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$('#containerElementThatAjaxdDataWillGoInto').on('click','#return_to_signup_form_from_ajax_popup', clickHandler );
```

EDIT: Here is a further attempt at clarity.

You are ajaxing in new html, and you are appending it to `#popup_signup_step_two`. Awesome. So this new html also has a button that needs to have a handler associated with it. To do this we need to delegate an event handler to `#popup_signup_step_two` so we can listen for all clicks on whatever element we want inside of that dom element.

```
$('#popup_signup_step_two').on('click', '#return_to_signup_form_from_ajax_popup', function() {
    // do stuff here
});
```

Now that you have this setup (inside a document ready), any click to the element `#return_to_signup_form_from_ajax_popup` inside of `#popup_signup_step_two` will call your click handler function. Now inside your current click handler, you set `#popup_signup_step_two` to `display = none`. So, if you want to do that action again, you need to make sure you set the element to `display` `block`.

I hope this helps more, if we are still missing eachother somewhere, this is the time to start getting things into a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or give a link.

Comment: The problem is that I can't click #return_to_signup_form_from_ajax_popup because that is the html that was just added to the webpage (or so I assume is the reasoning). #return_to_signup_form_from_ajax_popup isn't doing anything with ajax, it's only switching css values to show the login form again.

Comment: My real question for you is "what do I place in #containerElementThatAjaxdDataWillGoInto if I'm not actually using ajax on that click?"

Comment: I've added more info, hope it helps answer that.

Answer (score 2):

If your `$('#return_to_signup_form_from_ajax_popup')` click handler is being bound on document.ready, you will need to use event delegation instead. Event delegation is used to bind events to current and **future** elements.

See http://api.jquery.com/on/ and http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/ for more information on event delegation.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using $.ajax() use $('#popup_signup_step_two').load()

check [here](http://api.jquery.com/load/) for reference on the method